# IndexOutofBounds when sorting arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist

I'm in the process of adding Actionbarsherlock to my app to update the UI for Android 2.2/2.3 users.  ABS is working great but I found an issue with older devices where the ListView would hang after the app was opened after a reboot.  The app lists all apps with Internet Permission and then adds a few special apps (the app is a firewall) and would hang while trying to display the information.

Originally the code cached the apps after building the list using standard arrays.  I want to move the app away from the caching since i think that's a huge reason for some of the hanging.  So I've been moving everything from arrays to ArrayLists for easier usage.  I ran into one IndexOutofBounds but corrected that one but this one is stumping me completely.  Here is my code for getting the apps and sorting code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if any other code is needed please ask!
Thanks in advance!

App list code:

```
int count = 0;
    try {
        final PackageManager pkgmanager = ctx.getPackageManager();
        final List<ApplicationInfo> installed = pkgmanager
                .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        final HashMap<Integer, DroidApp> map = new HashMap<Integer, DroidApp>();
        final Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        boolean changed = false;
        String name = null;
        String cachekey = null;
        final String cacheLabel = "cache.label.";
        DroidApp app = null;
        for (final ApplicationInfo apinfo : installed) {
            count = count + 1;
            if(applist != null){
                applist.doProgress(count);
            }
            boolean firstseen = false;
            app = map.get(apinfo.uid);
            // filter applications which are not allowed to access the
            // Internet
            if (app == null
                    && PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED != pkgmanager
                            .checkPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                                    apinfo.packageName)) {
                continue;
            }
            // try to get the application label from our cache -
            // getApplicationLabel() is horribly slow!!!!
            cachekey = cacheLabel + apinfo.packageName;
            name = prefs.getString(cachekey, "");
            if (name.length() == 0) {
                // get label and put on cache
                name = pkgmanager.getApplicationLabel(apinfo).toString();
                edit.putString(cachekey, name);
                changed = true;
                firstseen = true;
            }
            if (app == null) {
                app = new DroidApp();
                app.uid = apinfo.uid;
                app.names = new ArrayList<String>();
                app.names.add(name);
                app.appinfo = apinfo;
                map.put(apinfo.uid, app);
            } else {
                app.names.add(name);
            }
            app.firstseen = firstseen;
            // check if this application is selected
            if (!app.selected_wifi
                    && Arrays.binarySearch(selected_wifi, app.uid) >= 0) {
                app.selected_wifi = true;
            }
            if (!app.selected_3g
                    && Arrays.binarySearch(selected_3g, app.uid) >= 0) {
                app.selected_3g = true;
            }
            if (!app.selected_roaming
                    && Arrays.binarySearch(selected_roaming, app.uid) >= 0) {
                app.selected_roaming = true;
            }
            if (!app.selected_vpn
                    && Arrays.binarySearch(selected_vpn, app.uid) >= 0) {
                app.selected_vpn = true;
            }
        }
        if (changed) {
            edit.commit();
        }
        /* add special applications to the list */
        List<DroidApp> special = new ArrayList<DroidApp>();
                special.add(new DroidApp(
                        SPECIAL_UID_ANY,
                        "(Any application) - Same as selecting all applications", false, false, false, false));
                special.add(new DroidApp(SPECIAL_UID_KERNEL, "(Kernel) - Linux kernel", false, false, false, false));
                special.add(new DroidApp(android.os.Process.getUidForName("root"), "(root) - Applications running as root", false, false, false, false));
                special.add(new DroidApp(android.os.Process.getUidForName("media"),"Media server", false, false, false, false));
                special.add(new DroidApp(android.os.Process.getUidForName("vpn"), "VPN networking", false, false, false, false));
                special.add(new DroidApp(android.os.Process.getUidForName("shell"), "Linux shell", false, false, false, false));
                special.add(new DroidApp(android.os.Process.getUidForName("gps"), "GPS", false, false, false, false));
        for (int i = 0; i < special.size(); i++) {
            app = special.get(i);   
            if (app.uid != -1 && !map.containsKey(app.uid)) {
                // check if this application is allowed
                if (Arrays.binarySearch(selected_wifi, app.uid) >= 0) {
                    app.selected_wifi = true;
                }
                if (Arrays.binarySearch(selected_3g, app.uid) >= 0) {
                    app.selected_3g = true;
                }
                if (Arrays.binarySearch(selected_roaming, app.uid) >= 0) {
                    app.selected_roaming = true;
                }
                if (Arrays.binarySearch(selected_vpn, app.uid) >= 0) {
                    app.selected_vpn = true;
                }
                map.put(app.uid, app);
            }
        }
        /* convert the map into an array */
        applications = new ArrayList<DroidApp>(map.values());
        return applications;
```

Sorting code:

```
class ApplicationSort implements Comparator<DroidApp> {

    @Override
    public int compare(DroidApp o1, DroidApp o2) {
        if (o1.firstseen != o2.firstseen) {
            return (o1.firstseen ? -1 : 1);
        }
        boolean o1_selected;
        boolean o2_selected;

        boolean vpnenabled = getApplicationContext()
                .getSharedPreferences(Api.PREFS_NAME, 0).getBoolean(
                        Api.PREF_VPNENABLED, false);
        boolean roamenabled = getApplicationContext()
                .getSharedPreferences(Api.PREFS_NAME, 0).getBoolean(
                        Api.PREF_ROAMENABLED, false);

        if (vpnenabled && !roamenabled) {
            o1_selected = o1.selected_3g || o1.selected_wifi
                    || o1.selected_vpn;
            o2_selected = o2.selected_3g || o2.selected_wifi
                    || o2.selected_vpn;

            if (o1_selected == o2_selected) {
                return String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(
                        o1.names.get(0).toString(), o2.names.get(0).toString());
            }
            if (o1_selected)
                return -1;
        }
        if (roamenabled && !vpnenabled) {
            o1_selected = o1.selected_3g || o1.selected_wifi
                    || o1.selected_roaming;
            o2_selected = o2.selected_3g || o2.selected_wifi
                    || o2.selected_roaming;

            if (o1_selected == o2_selected) {
                return String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(
                        o1.names.get(0).toString(), o2.names.get(0).toString());
            }
            if (o1_selected)
                return -1;
        }
        if (roamenabled && vpnenabled) {
            o1_selected = o1.selected_3g || o1.selected_wifi
                    || o1.selected_roaming || o1.selected_vpn;
            o2_selected = o2.selected_3g || o2.selected_wifi
                    || o2.selected_roaming || o2.selected_vpn;

            if (o1_selected == o2_selected) {
                return String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(
                        o1.names.get(0).toString(), o2.names.get(0).toString());
            }
            if (o1_selected)
                return -1;
        }
        if (!roamenabled && !vpnenabled) {
            o1_selected = o1.selected_3g || o1.selected_wifi;
            o2_selected = o2.selected_3g || o2.selected_wifi;

            if (o1_selected == o2_selected) {
                return String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(
                        o1.names.get(0).toString(), o2.names.get(0).toString());
            }
            if (o1_selected)
                return -1;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

ListView code that calls the sorting class

```
private void createListView(final String searching) {
    this.dirty = false;
    boolean results = false;
    List<DroidApp> namesearch = new ArrayList<DroidApp>();
    final List<DroidApp> appnames = Api.getApps(this, null);
    if (searching != null && searching.length() > 1) {
        for (DroidApp app : appnames) {
            for (String str : app.names) {
                if (str.contains(searching.toLowerCase())
                        || str.toLowerCase().contains(
                                searching.toLowerCase())) {
                    namesearch.add(app);
                    results = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    final List<DroidApp> apps = results ? namesearch
            : searching.equals("") ? appnames
                    : new ArrayList<Api.DroidApp>();
    // Sort applications - selected first, then alphabetically
    Collections.sort(apps, new ApplicationSort());
```

Comment: My friend, It is obviously a very tough (and offcourse boring) task to read the long code and find the problem for you. You better check the logcat data. Try to find out the problem with the hint from the line number shown there. If it is not possible then post the logcat

Comment: The logcat points to the sorting class.  However, the sorting class isn't the issue since that code worked with the previous arrays.  It's the arraylist that's the issue and debugging and logcat have led me no where.

Comment: Maybe you should do all of that processing off the UI thread.

Comment: That's what I'm doing by moving to the ArrayList.  I moved it to an AsyncTask that does it in the background.  What happens now in the current form is it reads all the apps and then hits the IndexOutofBounds while doing the sort before drawing the ListView on screen.

Comment: Have you tried configuring an exception breakpoint in Eclipse?  From the Run menu, select Add Java Exception Breakpoint, and enter ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (caught and uncaught).  The debugger will stop at the point the exception is thrown, allowing you to examine the state of the world.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see what is `DroidApp`, but you are using something like this:

```
o1.names.get(0) and o2.names.get(0)
```

Is it possible that some of the `DroidApps` have empty names lists?

Comment: No.  If I comment out the call to the sorting class the ListView populates correctly.  However, I just noticed that some of my entries for the special apps are blank.  Due to those strings being blank I assume that could cause the IndexOutofBounds when trying to sort?